Fixing Audio Sync Issues on Laptop Built-in Speakers
When I use the laptop's built-in speakers, YouTube and other videos are out of sync, but when I use Bluetooth speakers or headphones, everything works normally. How can I fix this?
and using windows everything works normal.
the laptop is hp dragonfly g4.
